# How to improve this function in Javascript which will accept any number of argument?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I want to improve this function. I have 6 types of function whereas their work is almost same just the passed parameter and global values are different. That's why I didn't fin any way to improve this and they are too much redundant .
this is my code:

```
var $param1 = $(document).find('select#param1');
var $param2 = $(document).find('select#param2');
var $arg1 = $(document).find('select#arg1');
var $arg2 = $(document).find('select#arg2');
var $arg3 = $(document).find('select#arg3');

function paramValueSet(p1, p2) {

    $param1.val(p1);
    $param2.val(p2);
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
}


function argValueSet(a1, a2, a3) {

    $arg1.val(a1);
    $arg2.val(a2);
    $arg3.val(a3);
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

You can see from their structure that they are almost similar. Is there any way I can write these in just one function? 
I know we can use spread operator, or arguments count here, but as the inner work is different for selecting the exact input that's why I am facing issues to solve this. And sometimes the **number of parameters** can be **eight/nine** so then it would be repetitive to sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var params = [
    $(document).find('select#param1'),
    $(document).find('select#param2'),
];

var args = [
    $(document).find('select#arg1'),
    $(document).find('select#arg2'),
    $(document).find('select#arg3')
];

function setValue(targets, values) {
    targets.forEach((e, index) => e.val(values[index]));
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
}

const values = [p1, p2];
setValue(params, values);

const values = [a1, a2, a3];
setValue(params, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example how you can do this.

```js
const one = $(document).find('#one');
const two = $(document).find('#two');
const three = $(document).find('#three');
const four = $(document).find('#four');
const five = $(document).find('#five');

function setValues(elements, values) {
  elements.forEach((e, i) => e.val(values[i]));
}

setValues([one, two], [2, 3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="one">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="three">
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="four">
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="five">
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a same function which takes in array of objects and change each value.

```
function setValues(objects){
   objects.forEach(({variable, newValue}) => variable.val(newValue));
   $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

For the first function call the method like below

```
setValues([
              {variable: $param1, value: "param1"},
              {variable: $param2, value: "param2"}
])
```